# Google Cloud Endpoints .api file not generated

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using GAE/J to create Google Could Endpoints using `@Api` and `@ApiMethod` annotations.

I successfully created an API and was able to test and view it on APIs Explorer but the `<appname>-v1.api` file is no more generated after I added one more method to the Api class.

I tried removing the new method to check if that was a problem, but even with just the old methods, the `.api` is not getting generated.

Comment: What GAE SDK version are you using? And if you are using Eclipse plugin, check the error log when you generate the client libraries, under `Window -> Show View -> Error Log` to get more info and post it...

Comment: Can you provide the code for your API class(es)?

Comment: Thanks for the response but i found the solution. There was a problem in the Entity's class (JavaBean) ; there were 2 setters for 1 parameter.